# Code doesn't work when upgrading from v3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

when I upgrade d3.js from v3.5 to 5.9.2 (the latest actually), my graph display correctly, but the legend items doesn't display. In my code, the `data` exist, but I have only `<div class="legend"></div>` without inner `<div data-id="DATA">DATA</div>`. I don't know if the code below is correct for v5. Thank you for your help.

```
d3.select(".segLegend")
  .insert("div", ".chart")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data(names)
  .sort()
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("data-id", function(id) {
  return id;
})
  .each(function(id) {
  d3.select(this)
    .append("span")
    .style(
    "background-color",
    $scope.openGraphModal.chart.color(id)
  );
  d3.select(this)
    .append("span")
    .html(id);
  if (id !== findSupplier.commodity.supplier.name) {
    $(this).toggleClass('c3-legend-item-hidden');
  }
})
```

The DOM with V3
[image]
The DOM with V5
[image]

Comment: After skimming that code it seems to me that there is nothing that works differently in v5 compared to v3. Are you sure that this works properly on v3?

Comment: I add two screenshot for compare v3 and v5.

Comment: So, is *everything else* exactly the same? Is the D3 version the only difference?

Comment: When I remove the `.sort()`, it's works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a first and quick look this is a strange problem, hard to identify, because in a D3 code we don't use the `sort` method at the position you did: at that position, that `sort` is worthless. Have a look (using v3):

```js
const data = [1,3,5,4,2];
const divs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .sort()
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(Number)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, nothing is sorted. The `sort` method should be used after appending the real DOM elements (again, v3):

```js
const data = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2];
const divs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .sort()
  .html(Number)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, `sort` at this correct position works with v5 as well:

```js
const data = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2];
const divs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .sort()
  .html(Number)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

#### Your problem

When you put `sort` in that strange (and useless) position in the enter selection in a code that uses D3 v4/5, not only it doesn't sort anything but, the most important, it avoids the DOM elements being appended:

```js
const data = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2];
const divs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .sort()
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .html(Number)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The snippet remains blank.

The solution is moving the `sort` to the correct position, not only because of the problem you're facing but also because, where it is right now, it's useless in v3 as well.